# Clarification on specific heat of materials

Tags: thermodynamics

At a temperature of 25 °C, the heat required to raise the temperature of 1 kg of water by 1 K is 4179.6 joules, meaning that the specific heat of water is 4179.6 J·kg−1·K−1. Does this also mean that to reduce temperature of 1 kg of water by 1 K, 4179.6 joule heat has to be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the process works both ways.

Comment: AKA : Energy is not created or destroyed.